# API call slow- unsure how to improve performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, axios

I have a page, that calls to an API with specific id to get the id's information. On the same page, I make a call to the a different API randomly generates id's so that it can suggest products to the user.

I'm finding that the API that calls random id's is very delayed compared to the page. Does anyone know how I can make this part of the page load as quick as the other page?

Page where both API calls are being shown:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import GetSingleProduct from '../Hooks/getSingleProduct'
import { AppContext } from '../Context/Context'
import '../Assets/Styles/Product.css'
import FooterIcons from '../Components/Banners/FooterIcons'
import Recommended from '../Components/Recommended'

function Product() {
  // able to use useParams to direct to the page with the id of the product that has been clicked
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { singleProduct, isLoading, error } = GetSingleProduct(`https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products/${id}.json`)
  const [clickedColour, setClickedColour] = useState([])


  // const disablePlusBtn = () => {
  //   singleProduct.quantity === 10 || singleProduct.quantity === 0 ?
  //     <button className='cursor-not-allowed'>+</button> && setDisableBtn(true)
  //     : <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
  // }


  // useContext for the add to cart 
  const CartState = useContext(AppContext);
  const dispatch = CartState.dispatch;


  const handleColour = (index) => {
    setClickedColour(prevstate =>
    ({
      ...prevstate, [index] // copies prev state
        : !prevstate[index]
    }))
    console.log(setClickedColour)
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div className='routeTaken'>
        <ol>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/shop'>Shop</Link></li>
          <li>Current page</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div className='productInfo'>
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {isLoading ?
          (<div>Loading...</div>) :
          <div id={singleProduct.id}>
            <img src={singleProduct.api_featured_image} alt={singleProduct.product_type}></img>
            <p>{singleProduct?.product_type ? singleProduct.product_type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.product_type.slice(1).toLowerCase().split('_').join(' ') : singleProduct.product_type}</p>

            <h1>{singleProduct?.brand ? singleProduct.brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.brand.slice(1).toLowerCase() : singleProduct.brand} {singleProduct?.name ? singleProduct.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + singleProduct.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() : singleProduct.name}</h1>
            <h2> £{singleProduct.price === '0.0' || singleProduct.price === null ? '8.50' : Number(singleProduct.price).toFixed(2)}</h2>
            <h3>{singleProduct.description}</h3>
            {/* {singleProduct.map(colour => 
            <h1>{colour.product_colors}</h1>)} */}
            <div className="colourList grid grid-cols-4">
              {singleProduct.product_colors?.map((colour, index) => {
                return (
                  <button onClick={() => handleColour(index)} className='colourItem' key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: colour.hex_value }}>
                    {colour.hex_value}
                    {clickedColour[index] ?
                      (<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4.5 12.75l6 6 9-13.5" />
                      </svg>
                      ) : (null)}
                  </button>
                )
              })}
            </div>
              <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ADD', payload: singleProduct })}>Add to basket</button>
            </div>
        }
          </div >
          <div>
            <FooterIcons />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Recommended />
          </div>
    </>
      )
}

      export default Product
```

I'm using custom hooks to call the APIs.

This is the API that is running well

getSingleProduct.js

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

const GetSingleProduct = (url) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    // output error code
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  
    const [singleProduct, setSingleProduct] = useState([])
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const singleAPI = async (url) => {
        // useCallback means that the API call will not be made everytime we make a change to the page e.g. reviewing a products info
        // useCallback means that the API call will only be called when it needs to be e.g. on page refresh. we use useCallback instead of useMemo as we want the function to be returned and not just the value
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
          const res = await axios.get(url)
          if (res.status === 200) {
            console.log('Success!');
            const productWithQuantity = {...res.data, quantity:1}
            setSingleProduct(productWithQuantity);
          }
          else {
            console.log(`Server error: ${res.status}`);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Fetch error: ${err}`)
          setError(err.message);
          ;
        }
        finally {
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      }
      singleAPI(url)
    }, [url]);
  
  
    return {
      isLoading,
      error, 
      singleProduct
    }
  
  }
  
  export default GetSingleProduct
```

This one is slower.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

const GetRecommended = (url) => {
    const [recommended, setRecommended] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getRecommendedProducts = async (url) => {
            // useCallback means that the API call will not be made everytime we make a change to the page e.g. reviewing a products info
            // useCallback means that the API call will only be called when it needs to be e.g. on page refresh. we use useCallback instead of useMemo as we want the function to be returned and not just the value
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url)
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    // const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.data.length)
                    // console.log(randomIndex)
                    // empty array to push the random numbers to 
                    // adds 4 random numbers to the empty array
                    const listRecommended =[]
                    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
                        listRecommended.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * res.data.length))
                    }
                    console.log(listRecommended)
                    // filter through res.data and filter out the ids that match with listRecommended
                    const filterOut = res.data.filter(({id})=> listRecommended.includes(id))
                    console.log(filterOut)
                    // converts prices that are set to 0.0 by the API and adds quantity of 1 to eahc object in the data array
                    const productsWithQuantity = filterOut.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            item.price === '0.0' || item.price === null ? { ...item, price: 8.50, quantity: 1 } : { ...item, quantity: 1 }
                        )
                    })
                    setRecommended(productsWithQuantity);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(`Server error: ${res.status}`);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(`Fetch error: ${err}`);
            }
        }
        getRecommendedProducts(url)
    }

, [url]);


    return {
        recommended,
    }
}

export default GetRecommended
```

Recommended.js (which is a component on Product page)

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import GetRecommended from '../Hooks/getRecommended'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
    import { faBasketShopping } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { useContext } from 'react'
    import { AppContext } from '../Context/Context'
    import savedHook from '../Hooks/savedHook'
    import'../Assets/Styles/Shop.css'


    function Recommended() {
        
      const { recommended } = GetRecommended('https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json')
      const { likedIndex, changeIcon } = savedHook()

      const listRecommended = []
  

    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
        listRecommended.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * recommended.length))
    }
    const filterOut =recommended.filter(({id})=> listRecommended.includes(id))
    console.log(filterOut)

  // filter out the ids that match with listRecommended


  return (
    <>
        <h1 className='recommendedHeader text-2xl'>Recommended</h1>
      <div className='recommended grid grid-cols-2 py-4 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-4'>

         {filterOut.map((item, index) =>{
            return(
                <div className='topProductCard h-full flex flex-col mx-1 transition ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100 hover: duration-300 hover:shadow-lg ' key={item.id}>
                < button className='mx-1 my-1' value={item.brand + item.product_type} onClick={() => { changeIcon(index); saveDispatch({ type: 'SAVE', saveIt: item }) }}>
                  {likedIndex[index] ?
                    (
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" className="redHeart w-6 h-6">
                        <path d="M11.645 20.91l-.007-.003-.022-.012a15.247 15.247 0 01-.383-.218 25.18 25.18 0 01-4.244-3.17C4.688 15.36 2.25 12.174 2.25 8.25 2.25 5.322 4.714 3 7.688 3A5.5 5.5 0 0112 5.052 5.5 5.5 0 0116.313 3c2.973 0 5.437 2.322 5.437 5.25 0 3.925-2.438 7.111-4.739 9.256a25.175 25.175 0 01-4.244 3.17 15.247 15.247 0 01-.383.219l-.022.012-.007.004-.003.001a.752.752 0 01-.704 0l-.003-.001z" />
                      </svg>
                    )
                    : (
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6" >
                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
                      </svg>
                    )
                  }
                </button>
                <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`} name={item.brand}>
                  <img className='topPickImage ml-8 mb-2 md:ml-12 xl:ml-20' src={item.api_featured_image} alt={item.brand + item.product_type}></img>
                  {/* To display the brand name with as sentence case */}
                  <div className='topPickText px-2 flex flex-col content-end'>
                    <p className='topPickProductType'>{item.product_type ? item.product_type.charAt(0) + item.product_type.slice(1).toLowerCase().split('_').join(' ') : item.product_type}</p>
                    <p className='topPickBrand'>
                      {item?.brand ? item.brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.brand.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.brand} </p>
                    <p className='topPickName'>{item?.name ? item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.name}</p>
                  </div>
                </Link>
                <div className='flex flex-row mt-auto mx-2 my-2'>
                  <div className='mr-auto mt-auto'>
                    <p className='topPickNumber'><span className='circleShadow '>£{Number(item.price).toFixed(2)}</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className='addToCart ml-auto mt-auto '>
                    <button className='basketTopPicks ' onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ADD', payload: item })}>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBasketShopping} />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
            )
        }
           )} 
      </div >
    </>
  )
}


export default Recommended
```

I'm unsure whether it is slower due to be a component in Product.js page or due to random number and sorting within Recommended.js?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your recommendation api is reasonably fast, one another improvement you can do is,  render  component before the GetSingleProduct.isLoading is true.

is change from

```
{
   isLoading ? 
     <Loader> :
     <div>
       <Product />
       <Recommended />
     </div>
}
```

to

```
{
   isLoading ? 
     <Loader> :
     <div>
       <Product />
     </div>
}
<Recommended  />
```

so that, you recommended api will trigger is parallel with getProduct api.

Also try to check the network time for these apis in network tab or using console. time / timeEnd.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Recommended component is already outside of the isLoading component